# Is there a way to give Python functions repeating sets of arguments?

Tags: python, function, arguments

I know about *args and **kwargs for repeating arguments, but is there a way to create a function with a variable number of *sets* of arguments?

E.g.

```
def move(dir1, num1, dir2, num2, dir3, num3, ... dirN, numN):
```

for a function that would allow you to tell something to move something any number of directions by any number of spaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could accept a list of tuples specifying a sequence of moves instead.

For example:

```py
def move(moves):
    for direction, num in moves:
        print(direction, num)
move([('N', 1), ('E', 2)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `*params` in the function definition, which each parameter is a tuple of a direction and a number:

```
In [1]: def move(*dir_nums):
   ...:     for direction, number in dir_nums:
   ...:         print(f"{direction=}, {number=}")
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: move(('N',1),('E',2),('W',3))
# direction='N', number=1
# direction='E', number=2
# direction='W', number=3
```